# authsmtp mail and rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authsmtp

I upgraded our application to rails3.1 and now I can't send mail using authsmtp service.

I have done this with gmail and rackspace mail before with no problems, but I keep getting denied on authsmtp.

Any help:

Configuration:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp  

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address  => "mail.authsmtp.com",
  :port  => 25,
  :domain => '<domain>',
  :user_name  => "<user>",
  :password  => "<password>",
  :authentication  => :login
}
```

those exact settings worked in rails 2.3

Comment: Problem I was having was specific to authsmtp.  The fix was to use port 2525 and set :enable_starttls_auto => false.  Not sure why it suddenly wanted port 2525, when port 25 worked before, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Gmail:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings       = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :domain               => 'my_domain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :password             => 'my_password',
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => 'authorized_user'
}
```

Comment: PS. This goes in the appropriate `config/environments/` file.

Comment: I have had no trouble with google mail, but in this case I am using authsmtp and it's not my app so I can't really change it.